# Why the history method doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm making an ipad web browser where of course I have an history. The UITableView works well, what doesn't work is the method to add new strings at the history array, and it doesn't give to me any error.
Here's the code:

```
.h

NSMutableArray *HistoryArray;

.m

-(void)viewDidLoad{
HistoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(void) addStringsToTheHistory{
    NSString *firstURL;
    [firstURL isEqual: @"http://www.google.com"];
    NSString *currentURL;
    [currentURL isEqual: field.text];
    [HistoryArray addObject: @"http://www.google.com"];
    if ([firstURL isEqual: currentURL]) {
        [firstURL isEqual: @"something"];
        [TableView reloadData];
    }else{
        [HistoryArray addObject: currentURL ];
        [TableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Anyone has any idea why it doesn't work well? Is it something about how the HistoryArray is initiated?

Comment: Why do you do firstURL =@"something"; ?

Comment: what calls "addStringsToTheHistory"

Comment: For semantic correctness, you shouldn't call the variables `firstURL` and `currentURL` unless they're actually of type `NSURL *`.

Comment: I'm gonna edit all. Then just one thing. How to call methods in other methods? How, for example, I call addStringsToTheHistory in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Edited. Please answer the question above here.

Comment: I think the iPad may already have a web browser. Just saying.

Comment: @user1176834 what are you *wanting* to have happen?  Just saying "it doesn't work well" is totally unclear.  And all of your `isEqual:` statements do nothing, with the exception of the one in the `if()` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The `isEqual:` method is an object equivalence test and returns a `BOOL` value. The lines:

```
NSString *firstURL;
[firstURL isEqual: @"http://www.google.com"];
NSString *currentURL;
[currentURL isEqual: field.text];
```

don't actually set the variables `firstURL` and `currentURL` to anything.

If you want to test for equality between two strings you should use:

```
if ([firstURL isEqualToString:currentURL]) {
}
```

If you still don't get the result you expect - set breakpoints or use `NSLog` functions to inspect the contents of your variables in your `viewDidLoad` and `addStringsToHistory` methods.